.h file not find when use pod in Xcode which is export from Unity
after export Xcode from unity, I install pod, and in the Plugins/iOS，when import MBProgressHUD, it hints  .h file not find, the head search path and framework path already set, now don't know how do it
[![.h file not find in image][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/opS0L6A4.png
